# Why I am getting the following error: Invalid cross-thread access, while trying to access passwordBox value in a function

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I am trying to access the passwordBox value through

```
string str= passwordBox1.Password
```

in a function, I am getting the following exception:

> Invalid cross-thread access.

Troubleshooting Tips:
If you are attempting to access a file, make sure it is not ReadOnly.

Comment: Well presumably you're doing this in a non-UI thread. However, you haven't given us any details about that. Please provide more context. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: What is the context that you are accessing the PasswordBox?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to access the Control from a non-UI thread.
Try wrapping that code in `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` function, like so:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
{
    string str= passwordBox1.Password
    ...
});
```